# Random forest [R]: why is my OOB RMSE so much smaller than test RMSE?

Tags: cross-validation, random-forest, cart, goodness-of-fit, mse

I'm doing the kaggle challenge on [timetravel predictions](https://www.kaggle.com/c/ce263n-hw4/overview) where the task is to predict the duration (Y) of a uber trip given some information about the start and end coordinates and the time the trip was taken. I'm having trouble reconciling the `OOB RMSE` $(=485)$ from randomForest output and the `test RMSE` $(=3233)$ I computed on a test set. Theoretically I think these should be very similar?

I did a lot of data cleaning but basically this is how I divided between training (80%, N = 116,000) and test(20%, N = 29,000):

```
set.seed(20191007)
trainingset_id = sample(nrow(traveltime_tree_scaled), floor(0.8*nrow(traveltime_tree_scaled)))
trainingset_id[1:5]
traveltime_tree_scaled_train <- traveltime_tree_scaled[trainingset_id, ]
traveltime_tree_scaled_test <- traveltime_tree_scaled[-trainingset_id, ]
```

I also winsortized the training set by capping dependent variable (Y) at its 99th percentile value

```
traveltime_tree_scaled_train_w <- traveltime_tree_scaled_train %>%
  dplyr::mutate(depvar = if_else(depvar > quantile(traveltime_tree_scaled_train$depvar, 0.99),
                                 quantile(traveltime_tree_scaled_train$depvar, 0.99),
                                 depvar))
```

Then I used random forest to do the prediction using some given variables and some variables that I built

```
traindata  = traveltime_tree_scaled_train_w
testdata = traveltime_tree_scaled_test
continuous_covariates_tree <- c('start_lng', 'start_lat', 'end_lng', 'end_lat', 
                                'distance_miles')
categorical_covariates_tree <- c('hourofday', 'dayofweek', 'datemonth', 'dateyear')

numtree = 20  # 24 trees take 24min for a continuous Y with N = 116,000 and p = 9 (# of variables) 
seednum = 20191007

set.seed(seednum)
outputrf <- randomForest(x= traindata[, c(continuous_covariates_tree, categorical_covariates_tree)], 
                       y = traindata$depvar, ntree = numtree, do.trace = 1, importance=TRUE)
```

What's surprising is that the model outputs OOB RMSE of

```
sqrt(outputrf$mse[length(outputrf$mse)])
[1] 460.9522
```

but my test RMSE calculation yielded a much larger number

```
predicted_y <- predict(outputrf, testdata)
rmse_rf <- sqrt(mean((predicted_y - testdata$depvar)^2))
rmse_rf
[1] 3233.281
```

I feel like I may be calculating the test RMSE wrong somehow but I check with the function `MSE()` and got the same number.

I also calculated the Mean Absolute Error (MAE) and it is much more aligned with the OOB RMSE provided by random forest

```
mae_rf <- mean(abs(predicted_y - testdata$depvar))
mae_rf
[1] 485.2263
```

I also got the same weird results with a Decision Tree where `test RMSE = 3300.177` but `MAE = 502.4888`. I think in general RMSE should be similar to MAE?

What am I doing wrong here???

Comment: your model is overfitted on train data

Comment: @quester can you elaborate on what you mean? what can I do to not overfit the training data? For Decision Tree I pruned the tree to the cp with the smallest cv error. For Random Forest I didn't do any tuning because I though RF is largely self-tuning.

Comment: random forests if are too precise tend to overfit, try more shallow models and then compare train and test RMSE probably for train will go up and for test will go down

Comment: @quester how would I adjust the depth of the model? I though random forests are mostly self-tuning. And how should I determine the optimal depth?

Comment: less trees in forest? goal is to learn only large signals and maybe smaller signals but if you would focus on too small signals it's bad - these smallest signals are noise

Comment: @quester I only had 20 trees in this forest because it takes so long to compute. If I do 40 trees the OOB MSE goes down even further. So I'm using very few trees to start with and I should in practice use more. Also, I've done the same prediction with a single Decision Tree, and using the optimal cp, I'm getting around the same number for RMSE and the where the Decision Tree's MAE is only 10% of the RMSE --same problem as my Random Forest (I feel like RMSE and MAE should be roughly the same).

Comment: @quester: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.